# git asks me to pull everytime I want to push

Tags: git, github

I have been always using a GUI interface to manage my git repos.Now, I moved to command line and faced some issue. So I have created my directory, initialised the repo, added all the files to the trakcking list and pushed. The issue is that whenever I try to push the changes that I make locally to the remote Github repo, my request is rejected. Even though I am the only one who makes changes in the code, I get always this error :

> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.git pull
>   ...') before pushing again. See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git
>   push --help' for details.

What I usually do to fix the issue is to do as suggested: pull from the repo and then push but this doesn't make sense for me. I am always merging my local copy with the remote one which hasn't changed since the last commit.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: How it your repository history graph looking like? A screenshot for example would be helpful.

Comment: are you doing something like revert-reset to previous commits, then trying to push to remote again ?

Comment: Perhaps you should have cloned your GitHub repo as a starting point, instead of initializing a new one that has no shared history with your GitHub repo...